# How do I check if input is a fraction (Python)?

Tags: python

I have a bit of trouble with validation of user input. For this task, the user has to input a fraction in the form x/y (e.g. 3/5) and it is printed after the user types input. The problem here is that I do not know how to check if the user input is in the specified form.

Wrong inputs should be something like this:

```
Input a fraction then press enter: 2/3/4
That is not a valid fraction
Input a fraction then press enter: 66
That is not a valid fraction
```

My current code is

```
def main():
while True:
    try:
        question = input("Input a fraction then press enter: ")
        break
    except:
        print("Please enter a valid fraction in the form x/y")
print(question)
```

As you can see, I am stuck on how to validate the input. Can anyone help solve this issue

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a relatively simple validation. Basically check that there is only one `'/'` character, and both the numerator and denominator are digits.

```
def validate(s):
    values = s.split('/')
    return len(values) == 2 and all(i.isdigit() for i in values)
```

For example

```
>>> validate('65/2')
True
>>> validate('43')
False
>>> validate('4/3/2')
False
```

Comment: One enhancement that the OP may want to consider; verify that `values[1]` is not 0 as well.

Comment: This is a simpler and more easy to understand way than using regex.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!  it works! I wish I could up vote your answer but I don't have enough reputation points :(

Comment: @Matthew You can select this post as an answer via the check mark to the left if you feel it satisfactorily answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python's `Fraction` module:

```
from fractions import Fraction

try:
    f = Fraction('22/7/3')
except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
    print "That is not a valid fraction"
else:
    print "{}/{}".format(f.numerator, f.denominator)
```

However it will not catch plain numbers, as these can be expressed as such: 66 = 66 / 1

Answer (score 1):

To cover the most amount of possible inputs, use `regex`:

```
import re

if re.match(r'^\d+/\d+$', user_input):
   # good input, do something with it
else:
   print "You did some bad input"
```

Comment: Your regular expression will consider `5/6/` as a valid fraction.